Why Cython class is slower than Python dataclass
Here is my Cython data class:
cdef class BookL1:
    cdef readonly str exchange
    cdef readonly str symbol
    cdef readonly double bid
    cdef readonly double ask
    cdef readonly double bid_size
    cdef readonly double ask_size

    def __init__(self, str exchange, str symbol, double bid, double ask, double bid_size, double ask_size):
        self.exchange = exchange
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.bid = bid
        self.ask = ask
        self.bid_size = bid_size
        self.ask_size = ask_size

Here is my Python data class:
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True)
class BookL1:
    exchange: str
    symbol: str
    bid: float
    ask: float
    bid_size: float
    ask_size: float

I compare their creation and access times as follows:
from trade_types import BookL1 as CBookL1
from utils import BookL1
import timeit

def create_book_l1():
    return BookL1("binance", "BTC/USDT", 30000.0, 30001.0, 1.5, 2.0)

def create_cbook_l1():
    return CBookL1("binance", "BTC/USDT", 30000.0, 30001.0, 1.5, 2.0)

def access_book_l1(book):
    return (book.exchange, book.symbol, book.bid, book.ask, book.bid_size, book.ask_size)

def run_benchmark(class_type, create_func, iterations=1000000):
    creation_time = timeit.timeit(create_func, number=iterations)
    
    instance = create_func()
    access_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: access_book_l1(instance), number=iterations)
    
    print(f"{class_type} Benchmark Results:")
    print(f"Creation time: {creation_time:.6f} seconds")
    print(f"Access time:   {access_time:.6f} seconds")
    print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_benchmark("Python BookL1", create_book_l1)
    run_benchmark("Cython CBookL1", create_cbook_l1)

I am testing on macOS 14.6.1 with an Apple M3 chip. Here are my results:
Python BookL1 Benchmark Results:
Creation time: 0.200142 seconds
Access time:   0.105723 seconds

Cython CBookL1 Benchmark Results:
Creation time: 0.064651 seconds
Access time:   0.169590 seconds

Why is the Cython access time slower, and how can I fix it? You can find my results in cdef-test

In the Cython version, every access to cdef readonly double bid requires you to create a new Python float object.
In the Python version, bid already exists as a Python float object so it's a very very cheap lookup.
The Cython version will be a smaller size (at least when you consider the total size of the class and all the objects it points to) and will be quicker to access from Cython.  The Python version will be quicker to access from Python because it doesn't require boxing C types.

Is there any way to speed up the access speed of CBookL1?

No. You've made a trade-off here and you need to decide if it's the right trade-off for your use case.
